# How do you include/extend a JS lib with rollup, typescript, angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, rollupjs

I building on this project [angular2-google-maps-test](http://stevemichelotti.com/integrate-angular-2-google-maps-into-ionic-2/) and I want to include and extend this JS lib [js-marker-clusterer](http://gmaps-utility-library-dev.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclusterer/)

`npm install --save js-marker-clusterer`

which does not seem to be written as a `module`.

```
function MarkerClusterer(map, opt_markers, opt_options) {
  // MarkerClusterer implements google.maps.OverlayView interface. We use the
  // extend function to extend MarkerClusterer with google.maps.OverlayView
  // because it might not always be available when the code is defined so we
  // look for it at the last possible moment. If it doesn't exist now then
  // there is no point going ahead :)
  this.extend(MarkerClusterer, google.maps.OverlayView);
  this.map_ = map;
...

}
window['MarkerClusterer'] = MarkerClusterer;
```

I want to do something like this:

```
// js-marker-clusterer.d.ts file
declare module "js-marker-clusterer" {
  export class MarkerClusterer {
    constructor(map: any, opt_markers?: any, opt_options?: any);
    map_: any;
    markers_: any[];
    clusters_: any[];
    ready_: boolean;
    addMarkers(markers: any[], opt_nodraw: boolean) : void;
    removeMarker(marker: any, opt_nodraw: boolean) : boolean;
    removeMarkers(markers: any[], opt_nodraw: boolean) : boolean;
  }
}
```

and then extend that class in typescript

```
/// <reference path="./js-marker-clusterer.d.ts" />
export class MyMarkerClusterer extends MarkerClusterer {
  constructor(map: any, opt_markers?: any, opt_options?: any) {
    super(map, opt_markers, opt_options);
  }   
}
```

but in `rollupjs` I keep getting this error:

```
[21:20:47]  bundle failed: 'MarkerClusterer' is not exported by node_modules/js-marker-clusterer/src/markerclusterer.js  MEM: 469.6MB
            (imported by src/angular2-marker-clusterer/my-marker-clusterer.ts). For help fixing this 
            error see https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/Troubleshooting#name-is-not-exported-by-module
```

My guess is that I need to add something to the `rollup.config.js` file, but I tried to add it as a `plugin` and that did not work.

```
  /**
   * plugins: Array of plugin objects, or a single plugin object.
   * See https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/Plugins for more info.
   */
  plugins: [
    builtins(),
    //commonjs(),
    commonjs({
      namedExports: {
        'node_modules/angular2-google-maps/core/index.js': ['AgmCoreModule'],
        'node_modules/js-marker-clusterer/src/markerclusterer.js': ['MarkerClusterer']
      }
    }),
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I don't know about the Typescript part, but I think instead of the commonjs plugin you should try the [rollup-plugin-legacy](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-legacy).

```
legacy({
    'node_modules/js-marker-clusterer/src/markerclusterer.js': 'MarkerClusterer'
})
```

Remember to change the import statement accordingly.